# How can I calculate relative time between two time stamps in hours in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

In the example dataframe below, how can I convert t_relative into hours? For example, the relative time in the first row would be 49 hours.

```
      tstart             tend                t_relative
0   2131-05-16 23:00:00 2131-05-19 00:00:00 2 days 01:00:00
1   2131-05-16 23:00:00 2131-05-19 00:15:00 2 days 01:15:00
2   2131-05-16 23:00:00 2131-05-19 00:45:00 2 days 01:45:00
3   2131-05-16 23:00:00 2131-05-19 01:00:00 2 days 02:00:00
4   2131-05-16 23:00:00 2131-05-19 01:15:00 2 days 02:15:00
```

t_relative was calculated with the operation, df['t_relative'] = df['tend']-df['tstart'].

Comment: Where are you stuck?  Is this not simple arithmetic on the `timedelta`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can divide `Timedelta`:

```
df['t_relative']/pd.Timedelta('1H')
```

Output:

```
0    49.00
1    49.25
2    49.75
3    50.00
4    50.25
Name: t_relative, dtype: float64
```